# Python Methode RSBF

Tags: python

I do not know why my code goes in an infinite loop 
I have a heuristic method that calculates the distance of manathan

```
def RSBF(a,limite):

    if heuristique(a)==0:
        return a
    fils=creer_fils(a)
    #fils_2=copy.deepcopy(fils)

    if len(fils)==0:
        return 0,limite
    V=[]
    #fils_2.remove(min(fils_2))

    for succ in fils :
        sc=heuristique(succ)
        k=max(sc+1,heuristique(a))

        V.append(k)

    while True:

        succmeilleur=[meilleur_successeur(fils),min(V)]#the best node et values

        #print(heuristique(succmeilleur))
        if succmeilleur[1] >= limite:

            return 0,succmeilleur[1] 
               #l=copy.deepcopy(min(V))

        valeur_v=V[deuxieme_valeur(V,V.index(min(V)))]#return the second lowest values

        resultat,succmeilleur[1]=RSBF(succmeilleur[0],min(limite,valeur_v))
        if resultat!=0:
            return resultat
```

Comment: As an FYI, while it's easier to code in your native language, this makes it harder for others to evaluate your code who don't speak it. In general, you should try to use English when writing code. I know it may be difficult, but think of it as improving your English!

Comment: Have you tried multiple values of `a` and `limite`? That might impact the answer people give you.

Comment: a is a Matrix and limit is a infinity values (biggest values)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly how `heuristique` and other methods work, this code is a somewhat hard to diagnose. Especially since I don't know how to heuristically calculate something like this mathematically.

However, it's obvious that two things are happening in the `while True` loop:

- `succmeilleur[1]` is never >= `limite`

  `min(V)` is never arriving at something greater than `limite`. When you do:

  ```
  sc=heuristique(succ)
  k=max(sc+1,heuristique(a))

  V.append(k)
  ```

  `V` is being created in such a way that the minimum of `V` is never greater than `limite`. Make sure that `V` is returning the correct list in each loop, which I presume is a list where the minimum of `V` keeps going towards the limit.
- `resultat` always = 0

  This means that `meilleur_successeur(fils)` is never returning something that isn't 0. In other words, you should check out `meilleur_successeur` and make sure it's always getting the best successor from `fils`.

Comment: StackExchange discourages posting in other than English, so although I have a French translation of this answer I won't be posting in publicly.

Comment: Heuristique calculate the Manhattan distance